# Как применить функцию только к некоторым столбцам датафрейма?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
    
def pr(income):
    if random.random() > 0,8:
        return [int(round(income[0]*income[1] , -1 )) , income[0]+income[1]]
    else:
        return [income[0] , income[1]]
    
    
data[['Price1','Price2']] = data[['Price1','Price2']].apply(pr, axis=1)
```

Во фрейме data много столбцов, подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне изменить процедурой только два из них?

Comment: Так вы и меняете только два столбца. Так не работает как вы делаете?

Comment: @CrazyElf там походу проблема в функции

Comment: Да так не работает слева датафрейм а справа series

Answer (score 1):

используйте список в локаторе:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

def pr(income):
    if random.random() > 0.8:
        res = [int(round(income["a"]*income["c"] , -1 )) , income["a"]+income["c"]]
        return pd.Series(res, index=income.index)
    else:
        return income

df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,4], "b":[11,22,33,44], "c":[111,222,333,444]})
print(df)
```

```
   a   b    c
0  1  11  111
1  2  22  222
2  3  33  333
3  4  44  444
```

```
df.loc[:,["a", "c"]] = df.loc[:,["a", "c"]].apply(pr, axis=1)
print(df)
```

```
      a   b    c
0     1  11  111
1   440  22  224
2     3  33  333
3  1780  44  448
```

Comment: Извините мне не нужно все строки умножать, а только некоторые рандомные.  Исправил код вначале

Comment: я вам показал, как обратиться к конкретным столбцам, у вас же так вопросе написано. чтобы использовать свою функцию, примените ее к локатору.

Comment: я обновил ответ.

Comment: ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable   Оно работает там где else ? а там где условие выполняеться не работает

Comment: так вы приведите пример исходных данных в вопросе, как того требуют правила сайта.

Comment: Я ваш код выполняю, когда выполняеться основное условие , то не работает

Comment: ну я вашу функцию не проверял особо, а вы, оказывается, возвращаете серию, а список. так делать нельзя. я исправил ответ - поправил вашу функцию `pr`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, я тоже додумался )

Answer (score 1):

```
    import pandas as pd
    
def pr(income):
    if random.random() > 0,8:
        return pd.Series([int(round(income[0]*income[1] , -1 )) , income[0]+income[1]])
    else:
        return pd.Series([income[0] , income[1]])
    
    
data[['Price1','Price2']] = data[['Price1','Price2']].apply(pr, axis=1)
```

Спасибо всем, разобрался в итоге сам

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял, применять к столбцам или ячейкам, в вопросе одно, в тексте вопроса другое, но если для столбцов, то можно выполнять `.apply()` в цикле `for`:

```
for i in ['Price1','Price2']:
    data[i] = data[i].apply(pr, axis=1)
```

В список для цикла `for` закидываем значения всех столбцов, которые нужно изменить.

Comment: Да это надо применить для столбцов. Значения зависят от двух этих ячеек

Comment: @SashaKurzenev не совсем понял от каких ячеек(если правильно понял в каждой ячейки столбцов Price хранятся списки и вы перемножаете первый и второй элементы этих списков, а затем еще складываете их), но в любом случае цикл for будет работать поочереди  с каждым столбцом применяя к нему pr() через .apply()

Comment: Извините я програмист неочень.  Это прайс лист, там Price1 зависит от price1 и price2 текущей строки и price2 зависит от price1 и price2.   Если я делаю циклом то я price2 не получу когда считаю price1

Comment: Наверно просто циклом сделаю перебор строк да и все

Comment: @SashaKurzenev все равно плохо понял, то есть ячейка Price1 зависит от самой себя и соседней ячейки Price2? А ячейка Price2 зависит тоже от самой себя и от соседней ячейки Price1? Просто в таком случае у нас из за порядка выполнения функции ячейка Price2 будет зависеть от уже измененной Price1. Поидее, если поясните чему должны равняться новые значения в ячейках-могу попробовать написать нужную функцию

Comment: я хотел бы вас попросить не давать ответы с использованием циклов.

Comment: Price2 равно рандомной скидке в процентах (10% или 20% или 30%)  Price1 равен Price1 + Price2  То есть например Price2  = 10%  Price1 = Price1 + 10%

Comment: @SashaKurzenev а Price1 - это цена или тоже скидка? Значения в Price2 в формате строки или это число 10, 20, 30 без символа процента? Зачем склодывать со скидкой? Буду очень преезнателен, если добавите в вопрос пример таблицы-несколько строк оттуда, чтоб было понятно что в ней

Comment: @strawdog а почему? (в данной ситуации тут не так понял вопрос, но не понял почему в целом лучше избегать циклов?)

Comment: Потому что, если вы используете циклы с pandas, то в 95% случаев вы делаете что-то не так. Один из основных смыслов библиотеки pandas - векторизация = эффективность, быстрота, масштабируемость и удобочитаемость. Циклы - это прям последний аргумент.

Comment: @strawdog ну в данном случае с 2 столбцами цикл не особо роли играл, тут же их не 100, а так в целом согласен. Тут в принципе цикл не нужен, как я понял, тут проблема в функции, применяемой к 2 столбцам и по данным из ячеек 2ух столбцов она должна менять эти значения.